# Merge multiple dictionaries on multiple common keys and stack them up under specific titles

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, merge

If I have two lists of dictionaries

```
dictlist1 = [
    {"air": "xenon", "severity": "high", "ball": "cricket"},
    {"air": "nitrogen", "severity": "low", "ball": "tennis"},
]

dictlist2 = [
    {"air": "xenon", "severity": "high", "country": "india"},
    {"air": "nitrogen", "severity": "low", "country": "australia"},
]
```

I want to combine them on **air** and **severity** and look like this:

```
[
    {
        "air": "xenon",
        "severity": "high",
        "dict_name1": {"ball": "cricket"},
        "dict_name2": {"country": "india"},
    },
    {
        "air": "nitrogen",
        "severity": "low",
        "dict_name1": {"ball": "tennis"},
        "dict_name2": {"country": "australia"},
    },
]
```

I have written the code that will use one common key to separate them like this.

```
def find(lst, key, value):
    for i, dic in enumerate(lst):
        if dic[key] == value:
            return i
    return -1


def merge_dicts(*dict_lists, common_key):
    result = []

    for dict_name, dict_list in dict_lists:
        for d in dict_list:
            i = find(result, common_key, d[common_key])
            if i > -1:
                j = find(dict_list, common_key, d[common_key])
                if j > -1:
                    result[i][dict_name] = dict_list[i]
                else:
                    result[i][dict_name] = []
            else:
                temp = {common_key: d[common_key]}
                k = find(dict_list, common_key, d[common_key])
                temp[dict_name] = dict_list[k]
                result.append(temp)

    for dict_name, _ in dict_lists:
        for q in range(len(result)):
            result[q][dict_name].pop(common_key)

    return result
```

dict_lists will look something like this:

dict_lists = ("dict_name1", dict_list1), ("dict_name2", dict_list2)

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I found for now, guys.

```
def find(result, filter_obj):
    positions = []
    for index, item in enumerate(result):
        if all(item.get(key) == val for key, val in filter_obj.items()):
            positions.append(index)

    return positions


def merge_dicts(*dict_lists, common_keys):
    result = []

    for dict_name, dict_list in dict_lists:

        for d in dict_list:
            filter_obj = {}
            for common_key in common_keys:
                t = {common_key: d[common_key]}
                filter_obj.update(t)

            i = find(result, filter_obj)

            if len(i) > 1:
                raise ValueError

            elif len(i) == 1:

                dict_specific_keys = {k: v for k, v in d.items() if k not in result[i[0]]}

                result[i[0]][dict_name] = deepcopy(dict_specific_keys)

            elif len(i) == 0:
                t = {}

                for common_key in common_keys:
                    temp = {common_key: d[common_key]}
                    t.update(temp)

                dict_specific_keys = {k: v for k, v in d.items() if k not in t}
                t.update({dict_name: deepcopy(dict_specific_keys)})
                result.append(t)

    return result
```

It is working fine but I'd want to get a more efficient solution